# load partial page using AJAX in PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how I can load a partial page (div) into another div using AJAX in my php page.

basically I have a div with some php output stuff, and I need to put that div's content into another one using ajax but my code doesn't do anything (it doesn't put the div's content into the other one).

this is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function load() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo $actual_link; ?>",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response) {
            //  $("#ajaxContent").html(response);
                $("#issomeone").html($(response).find("#notis"));

                setTimeout(load, 4000);
            }
        });
    }

    load();
});
</script>
```

so the `#notis` div holds the php output and the `#issomeone` div is the div that i need to put the stuff in using ajax.

is there something missing in my code or I'm just doing it all wrong?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

THIS DOESN'T DO ANYTHING:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {


function load() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo $actual_link; ?>",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {
        //  $("#ajaxContent").html(response);
        //$("#issomeone").html($(response).find("#notis"));


        $('#issomeone').load("<?php echo $actual_link; ?> #notis");

        setTimeout(load, 4000);
    }
});
    }

    load();
});
</script>
```

Comment: [**`$('div').load(url)`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) ?

Comment: @PedroEstrada, can you please elaborate? also that link you sent is broken.

Comment: did you check whether the $actual_link outputs something? try using jQuery's load() function..

Comment: @user3806613 the link goes to the jQuery `.load()` documentation. If it doesnt work, search for `jquery .load()` in google.

Comment: @John, yes, the $actual_link out puts correctly. I echoed in my php page and I also echoed it in a javascript alert and both worked fine. I'm not sure how to proceed with jquery load function in my current code!

Comment: @user3806613 the way to use it would be `function load() { $("#issomeone").load("<?php echo $actual_link; ?>") }` then call `load()` or whenever you need it.

Comment: @user3806613: `$('#issomeone').load("<?php echo $actual_link; ?>");`

Comment: @John, wont that load the entire page into the div though! I need to load part of the page.

Comment: @PedroEstrada, so, i wont need the $.ajax part of my code?! i'm confused!!! also, looking at your code seems like you are loading entire page into the div as well which is not what i am trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

You are `find`ing the DOM element and then trying to set that as target element's innerHTML with `html()`.  You in essence have a type mismatch.

You would need to get the innnerHTML of #notis to pass as the parameter to this function so:

```
$("#issomeone").html($(response).find("#notis").html());
```

Alternately, you could append the node if you want to keep the whole `#notis` element

```
$("#issomeone").append($(response).find("#notis"));
```

But really, since you are using a straight GET, you might be better off simply doing:

```
$('#issomeone').load('<?php echo $actual_link; ?> #notis');
```

This provides a more simple abstraction to what you are trying to do more manually with `.ajax()`

I would however encourage you to not get in the habit of loading full HTML pages and then scraping them for some particular element.  It is better design architecture to have the AJAX target script serve up only content that is needed when possible.

Comment: issue with second one will be repeatedly adding elements with same ID. Not pointing out as fault in answer but more for OP to recognize

Comment: @charlietfl Good point.  If that `load()` wrapper function is intended to be called multiple times, the `append()` solution would not be good.